# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function--Slect2 not working

Tags: javascript, html, django, select, jquery-select2

I have included the below-listed js file in the head tag on an HTML page(index.html), after loading that page on a button click I append an HTML page to the current page(index.html) which contain a select box. But when I call select2 on his appended page am getting the below error,
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
Please help to solve the issue.

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           
            <script src="{% static 'reports/assets/plugins/bootstrap/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
        
           <script src="{% static 'reports/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'reports/assets/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'reports/assets/plugins/chartjs/chart.min.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'reports/assets/plugins/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'reports/assets/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'reports/assets/js/lime.min.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'reports/assets/js/pages/dashboard.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'reports/assets/js/chart.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'reports/assets/js/pages/charts.js' %}"></script>
            
            
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/af-2.3.0/b-1.5.2/b-colvis-1.5.2/b-flash-1.5.2/b-html5-1.5.2/b-print-1.5.2/cr-1.5.0/fh-3.1.4/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
            <!-- needed to use moment.js for our date sorting-->
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
           <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js" ></script>
            -->
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js" ></script>
            <script src="{% static 'js/form_validate/jquery_validate.js' %}"></script>
```

select2 initialized in the appended page,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                        
                        $("select").select2();
                    });
                      </script>
```

Also, this issue was not there when am using the select box directly on the main page itself.

Comment: Would be nice if you show domain where you use these scripts. Too low information from your side. But most common error you call `select2()` function before connect select2.min.js script and without `$(document).ready(function() { *your code* });`. Also try to wrap `ajaxComplete()` call to `$(document).ready`

Comment: What you mean by domain? Am using django and include the script portion in <head> tag of html page, after that I append another page with select box which calls the select2 method.

Comment: I mean website where issue happens.